# Prevent other apps from drawing over my app when in pin windows mode

Tags: android

We are writing a software for schools where we ask the users to activate pin windows mode on Android to prevent the students from leaving our app. Unfortunately, Android does not restrict the other apps from drawing over the currently pinned app and apps like Facebook messenger are still able to draw over our app while in pin mode and display the preview of the message.

Is there a way to prevent all other apps from drawing over the currently active app?

Note: As of now, I am using the accessibility mode to go to settings and disable the draw over permission of all the other apps. I restore them back to their original state of course later on. I find this solution to be very ugly and not user friendly however and was looking for a better approach.

Comment: You may be able to accomplish this with the Android Management API: https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements/dedicated-device

Comment: Kai I should have mentioned that our app will not be running on specialized devices. Everyone should be able to install our app on their phone and use it. I think that the Management API are intended for single purpose devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the method `View.onFilterTouchEventForSecurity()` , it allows to detect if there is a  motion event with the `FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED`, and will let you know if there is a view going on the top of your activity

```
@Override
public boolean onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(MotionEvent event) {
    if ((event.getFlags() & MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED) == MotionEvent.FLAG_WINDOW_IS_OBSCURED){
        // show error message
        return false;
    }
    return super.onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(event);
}
```

and if you want to avoid other app drawing over your app you can add `setFilterTouchesWhenObscured` to your views via XML or programmatically.

Comment: How does this help me to prevent draw-over views from appearing on top though? It seems like setFilterTouchesWhenObscured have something to do with filtering touch events and not with preventing other views from drawing over my view.

Comment: android:filterTouchesWhenObscured

added in API Level 9

Specifies whether to filter touches when the view's window is obscured by another visible window. When set to true, the view will not receive touches whenever a toast, dialog or other window appears above the view's window.

       android:filterTouchesWhenObscured = "true"
       android:filterTouchesWhenObscured = "false"

Comment: Yes, but it does not prevent the other apps from drawing over my app correct? I am trying to block the draw overs all together.